# Python GUI for my shell scripting

Tags: python, shell, user-interface, scripting

I have written some simple Linux shell script. Now I am trying to figure out is that can I have a GUI developed with python and trigger my shell scripts from the GUI. 
Is this possible. How can I do this. Any ideas or examples please.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking "is it possible to build a GUI with Python from which I can trigger shell scripts"?

Comment: 1) google "python gui" 2) open first answer, that is [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming). 3) choose framework 4) go to that framework's tutorials. **///** Worth a read as well, python's official [GUI FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/gui.html).

Answer (score 1):

**Just make sure the python executable is in your PATH environment variable then add in your script**

python path/to/the/python_script.py
Details:

**In the file job.sh, put this**

## !/bin/sh

python python_script.py

**Execute this command to make the script runnable for you : chmod u+x job.sh
Run it : ./job.sh**